# JSF: mensagens de erro dentro do bloco catch não aparece na tela

Tags: java, jsf

Tenho uma aplicação JSF e nela criei uma classe BaseBean para gerar as mensagens que aparecem na tela quando ocorre algum evento.

Pois bem, no ManagedBean quando faço a chamada da classe BaseBean para enviar uma mensagem ao usuário logo após uma instrução a mensagem aparece na tela. Mas quando o trecho de código está dentro de um bloco try/catch e este código levanta a exceção entrando no bloco catch. E quando faço a chamada da classe BaseBean para enviar a mensagem de erro para o usuário NÃO aparece nada na tela.

ou seja, no bloco catch a chamada da mensagem NÃO aparece na tela!

Chamada da classe no bloco catch:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

classe BaseBean:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

páginas:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Coloca o html também.

Comment: postei a página do link e do form.

Comment: O fato de cair no `catch` não tem muita relevância a não ser que você executa algo diferente. Tente não associar a mensagem ao form, usando o método que não recebe o `componentId` e passa um `null`.

Comment: Neste caso coloco somente a mensagem de erro, veja que a classe BaseBean os métodos são sobrecarregados. Mas não resolveu. a exceção é lançada no console já que faço a chamada do `e.printStackTrace()`, então eu estava pensando que a questão não é somente enviar a mensagem para tela e sim é levar a exceção lançada para tela! porque o sistema se comporta como se não houve um erro, responde a requisição normalmente só quando vê a resposta está com erro! no meu caso a geração de um relatório. ele cria e transfere o relatório. O problema só é identificado na hora de abrir-lo aí dar erro.